# How to pratically doublespend bitcoins?

Tags: transactions, doublespend

I tried to put bitcoins into an p2p exchange with bitcoin-qt. I added a to small transaction fee, so the coins are now stuck as "Unconfirmed". The offer from the exchange is overdue, so all that will happen if the transaction gets confirmed is that I get them back with an administrative fee.

I would like my coins right now and avoid paying the fee. I've read that you can double spend the coins back to yourself and if I add a higher payment fee than the first time this would probably override the original payment. How can I practically do this? I'm not a hardcore developer but feel comfortable using commandlines and know my way around computers.

Comment: have you tried to add another transaction with more transaction fee than you already paid at your first transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you are not double spending, since the transaction was never confirmed on the blockchain. Double spending is possible by 51% attack; what you are trying is to replace the transaction with one with desired fees, before it is confirmed on chain.

You can use https://github.com/petertodd/replace-by-fee-tools

Comment: Not really, there are many forms of double spending, only some of them involve transactions that have already been confirmed.